# WPF - How to properly Binding Header Items Count property of another component + custom text

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to put a counter and a description on a TabItem Header:

```
<TabItem  Header="{Binding ElementName=lista_etapas, Path=Items.Count,StringFormat=Etapas: {0}}">
```

But the StringFormat doesn't work. It only shows the Item Count property of the Datagrid 'lista_etapas'.

Expected: 'Etapas: 32'

Result:

[image]

Obs.: I Want to avoid using the <TabItem.Header>, because this creates some problems with my customs templates.

Comment: Inspect this element with Visual studio and check that the value is just 32, maybe `Etapas` is just hidden and the size of your headers needs to be adjusted.

Comment: It's not. I've verified this before created this post.

Comment: And how is your `lista_etapas` defined in XAML? Can you share some more code?

Comment: Ah ok. You should include this information in your post so we don't talk about things you already done. What happens if you put just random text in that string format or use single quotes around your string format like `StringFormat='Etapas: {0}'`

Comment: You just get the number like 32 or 2 @XAMIMAX  I assume this is due to the way the header is translated into a textblock by the tabcontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the "StringFormat" Property only works with binding Controls Property using a TextBlock/Label in header.

```
<TabItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lista_emendas, Path=Items.Count,StringFormat={}Total: {0}}" />
                </TabItem.Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is working :

```
<ListBox Name="lista_etapas">
            <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>B</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem  Header="{Binding ElementName=lista_etapas,Path=Items.Count}"  
                      HeaderStringFormat="Etapas: {0}">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Comment: This is a neater solution than my converter approach. HeaderStringformat huh.  Should have thought on, I knew there was a contentstringformat.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<TabItem  Header="{Binding ElementName=lista_etapas, Path=Items.Count,StringFormat={}Etapas: {0}}">
```

You need open, close brackets for StringFormat.